# NDK_ROOT not found cocos2d-x in ubuntu14.04

Tags: android, python, linux, cocos2d-x, ubuntu-14.04

I have a problem with cocos2d-x version 3.6 on Linux.

I want to create a new console project using the information found on [this](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Creating_A_New_Example_Project) page.

When I use the command `./setup.py`, I get the following message:

> `Check environment variable NDK_ROOT
>    ->Search for environment variable NDK_ROOT...
>      ->NDK_ROOT not found
>
> ->Search for command ndk-build in system...
>      ->Command ndk-build not found
>
> ->Please enter the path of NDK_ROOT (or press Enter to skip):
>    ->Check environment variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
>
> ->Search for environment variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT...
>      ->ANDROID_SDK_ROOT not found
>
> ->Search for command android in system...
>      ->Command android not found
>
> ->Please enter the path of ANDROID_SDK_ROOT (or press Enter to skip):
>   ->Check environment variable ANT_ROOT
>    ->Search for environment variable ANT_ROOT...
>      ->ANT_ROOT not found
>
> ->Search for command ant in system...
>      ->Command ant not found
>
> ->Please enter the path of ANT_ROOT (or press Enter to skip):
>
> Please execute command: "source /home/jmuniz/.bashrc" to make added system >variables take effect`

the problem is that i do not know where `the NDK_ROOT`, `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` and `ANT_ROOT` are.

Comment: *i do not know where the NDK_ROOT, ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and ANT_ROOT are.* ... in the docs, too

Comment: the same that you are pointing in the question... but few topics above ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not sure about ndk, android-sdk and Ant path I suggest you to download them and unzip them in a safe location.
Then restart setup.py again and use the know path of each installation.

You can download them here:

- NDK
  (https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html)
- Android SDK (https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html)
- Ant (https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi)